# Audio and Video lags on Elementary OS (Music App, YouTube etc.)

Tags: audio, videos

i have a audio problem on elementary os. when im listening music (music app, youtube etc.) it "lags" everytime in random situations for a half second. maybe every 2 minutes. Itś a fresh installation of elementary. hope you can understand, my english is not that good. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Epiphany web browser to watch youtube videos? If yes, try to install Chromium or Opera (from Snap Store) and check once again. On Epiphany I have the same issues.

Comment: I use Brave browser. And its not only the browser, but in the standard music app, or in melody from the app store the same problem. thanks for your help!